# Java issue with IF statement

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at Java, I have a problem that asks the user to enter 3 integers and it'll tell the user which is ODD.

I can get most of the program to work except for the instances when 2 entries are odd. I setup if statements like this which I know isn't efficient but im still learning.

```java
if (num1 % 2 == 1 && num2 % 2 == 1) {
    System.out.println("a is odd");
    System.out.println("b is odd");
    return;
}

if (num1 % 2 == 1 && num3 % 2 == 1) {
    System.out.println("a is odd");
    System.out.println("c is odd");
    return;
}

if (num2 % 2 == 1 && num3 % 2 == 1) {
    System.out.println("b is odd");
    System.out.println("c is odd");
    return;
}
```

None of those work all the way, it'll only give me the first letter back of either instance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *it'll only give me the first letter back of either instance* - what do you mean?

Comment: to check if number is odd you need check `if (num % 2 != 0) {
      System.out.println("num is odd");
   }` you can avaoid multiple if statement by calling single method to check for odd

Comment: Do you have any special requirements for your if statements? IMO in your case if with single condition would be much more appropriate. For example `if (num1 % 2 == 1) { sout(“a is odd”); }` and same blocks of code for num2 and num3.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just check one by one?

```java
public static void check(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (isOdd(a))
        System.out.println("a is odd");
    if (isOdd(b))
        System.out.println("b is odd");
    if (isOdd(c))
        System.out.println("c is odd");
}

private static boolean isOdd(int num) {
    return num % 2 != 0;
}
```

In case you want to print the results only when **exactly two** numbers are odd, then approach is same as your original snippet:

```java
public static void check(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (isOdd(a) && isOdd(b) && !isOdd(c)) {
        System.out.println("a is odd");
        System.out.println("b is odd");
    } else if (isOdd(a) && !isOdd(b) && isOdd(c)) {
        System.out.println("a is odd");
        System.out.println("c is odd");
    } else if (!isOdd(a) && isOdd(b) && isOdd(c)) {
        System.out.println("b is odd");
        System.out.println("c is odd");
    }
}

private static boolean isOdd(int num) {
    return num % 2 != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
    if(num % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println(num + " is even");
    else
        System.out.println(num + " is odd");
```